# What is the fewest number of playthroughs to get all the trophies?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-2.5-remix

In 1.5 Remix, I really hated the trophies just because of the number of times you had to play through the game to even be able to get all of them. I like a challenge, but making me beat it on each difficulty individually instead of having stacked trophies was annoying.

What is the least amount of times I can play through 2.5 and get all of the trophies in each game?

Comment: Not answering because it isn't an answer, but the achievement list is http://www.khinsider.com/news/Kingdom-Hearts-2-5-Trophy-List-Revealed-4276 and you can make some assumed calculations based on the list. Maybe two per game (with the exception of Re:Coded being 1)

Answer (score 2):

It has been an old question, but I asked myself the same, so I looked for the information. Time to give it an answer. It is possible to get all of the trophies in a **single** playthrough in each game.

All the trophies have been made so that such a thing is possible. For instance, for Kingdom Hearts 2 Final Mix, there is the **Critical Competitor** trophy, which ask you to finish the game in Critical, and the **Proud Player** one, asking you to finish it in Proud mode. If you finish the game in Critical (which is an harder mode than Proud), it will unlock both trophies, so that you don't have to finish the game twice. So, for both games, just make sure to start a party in Critical difficulty, as Kingdom Hearts Birth by Sleep Final Mix also have a **Critical Competitor** trophy. For the [other trophies](http://www.khinsider.com/news/Kingdom-Hearts-2-5-Trophy-List-Revealed-4276), as long you make sure to achieve their conditions at the right time in the game, it is possible to do all of them in only one playthrough.

There are some guides which can help you to achieve such a run, like for instance this [one](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/735143-kingdom-hearts-hd-25-remix/faqs/71174), which also confirms this point :

> All Trophies can now be earned in a single playthrough of each story.